# ruby code with the NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

When running the following Ruby code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ar=[]

class String
   def to_int
     self == self.to_i
   end
end

ARGV.each do |a|
  ar.push("#{a}")
end

ar.map(&:to_int).sort

ar.each do |x|
  print x + " "
end

puts ""
```

I am getting the following error:

> example.rb:14:in `sort': undefined method `<=>' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)

This program needs to be running with the command line argument with a list of numbers. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So what is the expected input and output of this program?

Comment: expedted output is:

ruby example.rb 5 4 1 3 2 

output:
1 2 3 4 5

Answer (score 0):

```
ARGV.sort.each { |x| print x + " " }
puts
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class String
   def to_int
     self == self.to_i
   end
end
```

This `to_int` method will return either a true or false. So when you run this line: `ar.map(&:to_int).sort`, the `map` method will map the entire array into true or false.

You array will look like `[false,false,true,false]`, which will fail when you run the `sort` function.

I'm not sure what the purpose of the `to_int` function is, you just need to map with the simple `to_i` function, then sort it.

```
ar.map!(&:to_i).sort
```

Make sure you use the `map!` so your original array is modified.

If you do map the array into integers, you will have to modify the print line to

```
ar.each do |x| 
  print x.to_s + " "
end
```

Otherwise you will get an error:

> String can't be coerced into Fixnum

Answer (score 0):

When I run this using Ruby 2.3.0, I don't get that error.
I tried Ruby 2.0.0p648 (which comes with OS X), 2.1.5, and 2.2.4, and they don't raise that error either.

It's a bit unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish here.
You're doing things that don't make any sense, but I'll assume you're trying to learn Ruby and you're just trying different things.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ar=[]

# This is "monkey patching" String, and is a bad practice.
class String
  # A method named "to_int" implies a conversion to integer. But the "to_i" method already does
  # that, and this method doesn't convert to an integer, it converts to a boolean.
   def to_int
     # Comparing the string to itself as an integer. Why would it ever be true?
     self == self.to_i
   end
end

# I'm assuming that this is intended to convert the argument list to a list of strings.
# But ARGV should already a list of strings.
# And this would be better done as `ar = ARGV.map(&:to_s)`
ARGV.each do |a|
  ar.push("#{a}");
end

# This creates an array of values returned by `to_int`, then sorts the array.
# Since `String#to_int` (defined above) returns booleans, it's an array of "false" values, so
# sorting does nothing. But then the value of the `sort` is ignored, since it's not assigned to
# a variable. If you want to modify the order of an existing array, use `sort!`.
# But if you're trying to sort the array `ar` by the numeric values, `ar.sort_by(&:to_i)` would
# do that.
ar.map(&:to_int).sort

ar.each do |x| print x + " "; end

puts ""
```

It seems like you're trying to print the arguments in their numeric order.
This can be accomplished with

```
puts ARGV.sort_by(&:to_i).join(" ")
```

Comment: Appreciate you help very much  Robin Daugherty . That solves my problem. Thanks a lot. :)